# Slowly sendkeys with c# selenium

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write slowly one by one with selenium ?
My code `drv.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@class='class id']"))[0].SendKeys(name);`
Is it possible to write the name slowly here example (n 1000ms , a 1000ms , m 1000ms , e 1000ms)

Answer (score 3):

I have not tested it. I don't like to use `Thread.Sleep();` because it freezes GUI.

```
public async Task SendKeysSlowly(int delay, string text, IWebElement element)
{     
    foreach(string str in text)
    {
        element.SendKeys(str);
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

usage;

```
await SendKeysSlowly(1000, "hello world", myelement);
```

Comment: I did not understand how to do

Comment: @guapo use like this: `await SendKeysSlowly(1000, name, drv.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@class='class id']"))[0]);` 1000 is milliseconds to wait after sending each char in the your text. Sorry for my bad english.